# Connecting to VPN

Tags: networking

I was trying to connect to my college vpn using Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client. I was told it does cannot be done using UNIX systems. Is there any way i can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [cisco website](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/compatibility/asa-vpn-compatibility.html#pgfId-244867), Ubuntu versions 12.04 and 14.04 lts 64 bit only are supported operating systems of Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client, version 4.1.

The following was taken directly from [the cisco website](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/vpn_client/anyconnect/anyconnect41/release/notes/b_Release_Notes_AnyConnect_4_1.html#ID-1454-00000002).

Download the Latest Version of AnyConnect
Before You Begin

To download the latest version of AnyConnect, you must be a registered user of Cisco.com.
Procedure

**Step 1**      Follow this link to the Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client product support page:

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps10884/tsd_products_support_series_home.html

**Step 2**      Log in to Cisco.com.

**Step 3**      Click Download Software.

**Step 4**      Expand the Latest Releases folder and click the latest release, if it is not already selected.

**Step 5**      Download AnyConnect Packages using one of these methods:

To download a single package, find the package you want to download and click Download.

To download multiple packages, click Add to cart in the package row and then click Download Cart at the top of the Download Software page.

**Step 6**      Read and accept the Cisco license agreement when prompted.

**Step 7**      Select a local directory in which to save the downloads and click Save.

**Step 8**      See the Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client Administrator Guide, Release 4.1